# Is there any way to update android app using phpmyadmin server?

Tags: java, android, phpmyadmin

Is it possible for an android application to check and update itself from phpmyadmin server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with php. Use PHP to make a connection with the database and get Data from phpmyadmin database. Then make a restful API with PHP to return you all fetch data.
 Restful API helps to create, read, update or delete information between different applications over the internet or HTTP protocol.
Now through your android app call this API and update your app.
you can follow this for more information.
[Rest API in PHP](https://phppot.com/php/rest-api-crud-using-php/)